# Javascript multiple confirm leave navigation box pop ups before closing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

A few years ago, I was Rick Roll'd badly. I was sent to a website where the classic "Never Gonna Give You Up" by Rick Astley music video was playing. When I went to exit the webpage, a confirm dialog box popped with the the first line of the lyrics to the song. I pressed OK, but then another box popped with the second line of the lyrics. This looped until I went through the entire song (many dialog boxes had popped up) and it then finally let me close the webpage.

How would I go about implemented something like this in my code for a webpage?

I have searched all over the internet and have came across multiple threads about using "onbeforeunload" or similar methods within HTML and Javascript, but all of the answers that pertained to this only allowed the developer to customize the message shown when the user tries to leave the site. I understand completely how to do that, but that is not what I am looking for.

I have seen a few people give answers to my question on other threads but the answers don't actually work. Many people say that it is impossible to do this, but then I question how websites like that Rick Roll website did such a thing then?

Thanks!

Comment: browsers give you the option to prevent multiple popups in a row now, something that wasn't available a few years ago assumedly when this happened to you

Comment: @jmore009 thank you, this makes sense. Especially since websites like that Rick Roll one do not work in my Chrome, but do work in my IE.